# Quick Fix to Sketchy look when Vertices are placed between Textures

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

Is there a quick fix to the sketchy look I get when extruding this plane I've created in Blender? The Vertices are placed ontop of this pickaxe texture, but the transparent part of the texture is placed against the other side of the vertices, giving it this weird sketchy looking effect. I could fix this by manually moving each vertex individually inside of the texture, but is there a faster fix that I'm not aware of?

Thank you, and I apologize for the weak explanation.

[image: weird sketchy effect when extruding texture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I figured out how to fix this issue quickly

1. In edit mode, enter edge mode and select all.
2. right click and select Edge Split
3. In the UV Editor, scale each subdivision by individual origins.
4. Done